# R - "row-wise" sampling from Matrix

Tags: r

Let's say I have 2x matrices:

```
x <- matrix(rep(1:5, 2), ncol=5, byrow=T)
prob <- matrix(rep(0, each=5, 2), ncol=5, byrow=T)
prob[1, 3] <- 1
prob[2, 4] <- 1

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5

> prob
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

I want to perform "row-wise" sampling from the matrices with `sample()`.  For example, `sample` will select one value from each row of `x` using the probabilities in the same row of `prob`.  In the above example, I want `sample` to return `c(3,4)` every time because the probability has been set to 3=100% for row 1 and 4=100% for row 2.

However, when I run `sample(x, prob=prob, size=nrow(x))`, I receive `3` and `4` is any order:

```
> sample(x, prob=prob, size=nrow(x))
[1] 4 3
> sample(x, prob=prob, size=nrow(x))
[1] 3 4
```

How can I perform "row-wise" sampling of the matrix `x`?

Comment: ```unlist(lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) sample(x[i,], prob=prob[i,], size = 1)))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vapply` (safer by specifying what you're expecting) to loop over each row:

```r
x <- matrix(rep(1:5, 2), ncol=5, byrow=T)
prob <- matrix(rep(0, each=5, 2), ncol=5, byrow=T)
prob[1, 3] <- 1
prob[2, 4] <- 1


vapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) {
  sample(x[i, ], prob = prob[i, ], size = 1)
}, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)
)
#> [1] 3 4
```

Comment: I ultimately went with @M's comment: `unlist(lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) sample(x[i,], prob=prob[i,], size = 1)))` but this answer is just as fast and I can actually mark it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

One option with `mapply` and `asplit`

```
mapply(sample, asplit(x, 1 ), prob = asplit(prob, 1), size = 1)
#[1] 3 4
```